# Why is the property type name similar to the class name in C#?

Tags: c#

```
public class MySettings
{
    public int MyNumber { get; set; }
    public string MyString { get; set; }



    private static MySettings DefaultSettings
    {
        get
        {
            return new MySettings 
            {    
                MyNumber = 0,
                MyString = "", 
            };


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a static property that returns an instance of type MySettings. The getter creates a new instance every time it's invoked. 
Essentially it looks like a convenience wrapper for creating objects.

MySetting is the return type, so the newed up object has to also be of that type.

Answer (score 0):

The property name is "DefaultSettings". Whenever the 'get' is called, it will create a new MySettings object.

```
MySettings settings = MySettings.DefaultSettings;
```

Here the "settings" local variable will have a my number of "0" and empty string.